# How to color image in php by pixel ??`

Tags: php, html, css, algorithm

I have 2 vector . The first vector save the gradiend of 1 color . For example: from 
green to white. I want to color an image via pixel . for example we give the cordinate of an pixel (X ,Y) and dhe color RGB 40 , 60 , 120 and to color this pixel ect.. 
Is any function in php that can do this ??

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for example using the [gd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) library and [`imagesetpixel`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetpixel.php).

Comment: please can you help me . i cant do this . please help me wih an exam